# How to add a DLL in a WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I actually have a C++ file that contains a lot of fonction, and right now I am trying to make a GUI using WPF. I made a DLL file from my previous C++ file (I compiled it with no issues) and I just want to add this DLL to my WPF project but I can't manage to do it.

I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170) but at the time of the import I can't find the Properties page as it is mentioned.

After some research I saw that I just need to right click on my project-> Add references and add my DLL but want I do that I have an error message saying that the reference is not valid and can't be added.

What I am doing wrong ? Is there a way to add DLL file in a WPF project ? What should I do to be able to use the fonction that I have already written in my .cpp file ?

Comment: Is this an unmanaged DLL? Then look up P/Invoke. Or is is a managed or mixed DLL created in C++/CLI? Then adding as reference should work.

Comment: [Platform Invoke (P/Invoke)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke), [.NET programming with C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170)